# Sprache -- Cannot recognise this sequence

Tags: c#, parsing, sprache

I want to match strings where the first character is a letter, then it is followed by multiple characters which are either digits or letters, then finally ends with a letter. For example `a11a11a` is correct but `a11aa11` is incorrect because it ends with a digit and not a letter.

I wrote the following code to do it:

```
var grammar =
    from first in Parse.Letter.Once()
    from rest in Parse.LetterOrDigit.Many()
    from end in Parse.Letter.Once()
    select new string(first.Concat(rest).Concat(end).ToArray());

var result = grammar.TryParse("a111a");
```

Unfortunately `LetterOrDigit.Many()` consumes the last letter too.

Any way to avoid this?

Comment: You want to use a [Regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference)

Comment: I think he wants to use Sprache, not a RegEx. Just because a Regex is simple for the given case doesn't mean it will be simple for other grammar rules..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```
Parser<IEnumerable<char>> A = null, B = null, C = null;

var letter = Parse.Letter.Once();
var digit = Parse.Digit.Once();

B =
    (
    from d in digit
    from cs in Parse.Ref(() => C)
    select d.Concat(cs)
    ).Or
    (
        from l in letter
        from bs in Parse.Ref(() => B)
        select l.Concat(bs)
    ).Or(letter);

C = (
    from d in digit
    from bs in Parse.Ref(() => B)
    select d.Concat(bs)
    ).Or(letter);

A = (
    from l in letter
    from bs in Parse.Ref(() => B)
    select l.Concat(bs)
    ).Or(letter);

var grammar =
    from _ in Parse.WhiteSpace.Many()
    from a in A
    from __ in Parse.WhiteSpace.Many()
    select a;
```

The clauses in the `Or`'s need to be in the correct order.

A commenter recommended the use of Regular Expressions. You can use them within Sprache:

```
Parse.Regex("[a-z]([a-z0-9]*[a-z])?")
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative Solution:

```cs
       var text = "a11a11a";
       var n = text.Length;
       var grammer =
           from open in Parse.Letter.Once()
           from content in Parse.LetterOrDigit.Repeat(n - 2)
           from close in Parse.Letter.Once()
           select open.Concat(content).Concat(close);
```

[Try it](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JFrA6S)